# wit.ai lacks documentation: missing status management

Tags: nlp, chatbot, wit.ai

is there a clear way to understand how the "status" should be set to an intent in wit.ai?
Looking at [last version of documentation](https://wit.ai/docs/complete-guide#advanced-topics-link) (after changing their approach) it seemed that many things were deprecated (which is fine) but documentation is still in a "non-up-to-date" state.
i.e. the "add status" button is not available in the UI.

I need to set a status (somehow the context) to better manage the topic of the conversation.

Any hint, at least on how to better understand?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for point out. I'm not sure how you land on this part but this should only accessible via the "Complete Guide (deprecated)" link in the docs home.[image]

More info on state here: https://github.com/wit-ai/wit/issues/737